# Prisma schema - Create a relation field from multiple possible foreign keys (OR relation)

Tags: prisma

How to create a `relation field` in prisma schema that target 2 possible `relation scalar fields` ?

For instance, in soccer, let's say we've got the following 2 models:

```
model Match {
    team1Id     Int
    team1       Team        @relation("team1", fields: [team1Id], references: [id])

    team2Id     Int
    team2       Team        @relation("team2", fields: [team2Id], references: [id])
}

model Team {
    id          Int         @default(autoincrement()) @id
    name        String
    matches     Match[]     @relation( /* What to put here ? */ ) // <----
}
```

What to put in the `Team.matches` relation field definition in order to allow `Team.matchs` to contain any match the team played from any side, as team1 or as team2 ?

Answer (score 7):

This is not possible in Prisma right now! I created an issue in our [repo for technical specifications](https://github.com/prisma/specs/issues/460) to think about ways for improving this!

---

**Workaround**

With Prisma you always need to have a relation field on both sides per relation. This means you need to have two relation fields on `Team`, one which represents the matches where the team played "as team 1", another where it played "as team 2".

```
model Match {
  team1Id Int
  team1   Team @relation("team1", fields: [team1Id], references: [id])
  team2Id Int
  team2   Team @relation("team2", fields: [team2Id], references: [id])
  @@id([team1Id, team2Id])
}

model Team {
  id             Int     @default(autoincrement()) @id
  name           String
  matchesAsTeam1 Match[] @relation("team1")
  matchesAsTeam2 Match[] @relation("team2")
}
```

Comment: This is not working for me with MongoDB. do I need any special handling for MongoDB. Id field type are String for me.